# What datatype of parameters can be used for IP address in Azure Devops pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

In order to pass value to azurepipeline yaml, during the runtime, I was looking for the proper data type of parameters to pass the ip address. Is this fine to add as a string ?

```
parameters:
- name: subscription
  type: string
  default: 'Mysubscription'
- name: DZoneResourcegroup
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: DZone
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: hostname
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: ip
  type: string
  default: ''  


    
trigger: none

stages:
- stage: Create_DNS_Record
  displayName: 'Create DNS Record'
  jobs:
  - job: Create_DNS
    pool:
      name: mypool   
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscription }}
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: 'az network dns record-set a add-record -g ${{ parameters.DZoneResourcegroup }} -z ${{ parameters.DZone }} -n ${{ parameters.hostname }}  -a ${{ parameters.ip }}'
```

Also looking for a better way than this to automate if possible and get notified if the corresponding record is already existing in the DNS Zone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use **string** as data type of the parameter to pass the IP address. Even if you check this [required parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/dns/record-set/a?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_dns_record_set_a_add_record-required-parameters) section of  **az network dns record-set** command then, you will find that it accept IPv4 address in string notation.

And you can also modify the process in your pipeline. Instead of running inline script you should run multiline script where you can use the `az network dns record-set <record-type> show` command to retrieve an existing record set then, run conditional statement to check if the corresponding record is already existing before creating.

The following example retrieves the record *`www`* of type A from zone *`abc.com`* in resource group *`MyRG`*

```
az network dns record-set a show --resource-group myRG --zone-name abc.com --name www
```

I would suggest to read this [Manage DNS records and recordsets in Azure DNS using the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets-cli) documentation for more information.